# Nested custom controls in wxWidgets

Tags: c++, user-interface, wxwidgets

## Background

I am working on several custom controls in wxWidgets and found that I'm unsure about the "clean" or "intended" way to realize complex, nested controls, meaning controls that could, in principle, be composed of several sub-controls.

Consider as an example a diagram view (for example for a UML diagram). This diagram consists of nodes and edges. Each node might contain a button to delete the node. I might also want a small zoomed-out overview image of the entire diagram.

## Baseline

My current implementation is (based on examples I found and on the manual) a single diagram control that handles all the drawing - edges, nodes, buttons, overview image, which is not that inconvenient because I don't want native controls anyway, and also handling all the click events on buttons based on finding their coordinates on the screen.

## Alternative

But I've wondered for a while if this is really the right way, and it has occurred to me recently that there may be a better one: Saying (for example) that `class Node : public wxPanel`, inside that `Node` is a button, and the rest of the `Node` (node color, etc.) is drawn by me on the `Node` background. Then I place many `Node`s inside a `class DiagramView : public wxPanel`, at the locations of each diagram node. I also place a `class Overview : public wxControl` inside the `DiagramView`.

This would mean I only add those `Node`s to the `DiagramView` that are visible at the moment.

I have added a sketch of my current implementation (upper) and the alternative (lower) below. Class borders are marked in thick dashed lines. Controls that are fully custom-drawn are red, panels are blue.

Also I realize that there are libraries for drawing graphs, this is merely an intuitive example but my question is more general: What is the right or intended way, or the best practice to build nested / complex custom controls? Is it better to custom-draw everything, like the generic tree view? Or is it better to inherit e.g. from panels, nest these, and only draw on their backgrounds and on atomic custom controls such as buttons? Or is all of this problematic for some reason? Any hint would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: You might get more responses to this on the wxWidgets forum.

Answer (score 1):

As almost always, there is no single best answer for all cases.
In your case, it's probably best to stay with the complete custom drawing, especially since you have it implemented and working. Otherwise another very important consideration is the overlapping of sibling widgets, which is not permitted. I.e. if Node 1, Node 2, Overview etc were wxPanel-s, they could not overlap. Overlapping widgets are not supported and allowing it will only exhibit weird behavior (which will affect drawing, event handling etc).

However there are situations when composite controls are best built from smaller ones, when any sibling overlapping is guaranteed not to happen. Among the advantages here could be aligning the components with sizers, easier text manipulation, less custom drawing if any.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you design your own control the same way you design a dialog: using sub-controls and placing them in a wxPanel with the help of wxSizer`s.

You need to override the base class virtuals `DoGetBestSize()` and `DoMoveWindow(...)`.

You should care of mouse/keyboard action if you need it instead of the default processing.

A second way is what you currently do: Draw everything and care about events on your own. That's hard.

A third way is to use the undocumented `wxCompositeWindow` class. It's used internally by wxWidgets to build some controls (generic wxSpinCtrl, wxDateCtrl, etc). You can search for it the source code and see how it works.